# Faster optimization for for-loops

Tags: python

I am doing this exercise:

> You are given an array and you need to find number of triplets of indices `i`, `j`, and `k`, such that the elements at those indices are `d[i] < d[j] < d[k]` and `d[i] + d[j] + d[k] <= t`, with `t` and `d`  given by user

I have the following code where it tries:

```
def test(t, d):
    d = sorted(d)
    total = 0
    size = len(d)

    for x in range(size - 2):
        for i in range(x+1, size - 1):
            for j in range(i+1, size):
                if (d[x] + d[i] + d[j]) <= t:
                    total += 1

    return total
```

The code works fine but when it comes to bigger cases, the code isn't optimized enough that it can compute it in less than 10 seconds. So I changed it up to this instead:

```
def test(t, d):
  d = sorted(d)
  total = 0
  size = len(d)

  for i in range(size - 2):
    j = i +1
    k = size - 1
    
    while k > j:
        if (d[i] + d[j] + d[k]) <= t:
            total = k - j + total
            j += 1
        else:
            k -= 1
            
  return total
```

Sample case:

```
t = 8
d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Output: 3

This code works better compared to before but it is still not optimized enough. Is there something I could do or use to improve the optimization.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Can you give some example inputs and expected outputs? The second code isn't indented correctly.

Comment: The triple loop at the top looks like it could be replaced with `for x, y, z in itertools.combinations(d, 3): total += x + y + z <= t`, or even `for s in map(sum, itertools.combinations(d, 3)): total += s <= t`

Comment: Can the numbers be negative?

Answer (score 0):

So it *looks* like you're trying to find the count of all triplets where the sum is less than or equal to a specific value (now confirmed with your question update).

If that's the case and, since you're sorting the data, you can optimise the non-inner loops to remove checking for impossible situations.

For example, if `d[x]` is *already* greater than `t`, there's *no* point in running the two non-outer loops for that, since everything after that is greater than `d[x]`.

Ditto for `d[x] + d[i]` being greater than `t`, there's no point running the inner loop. In other words, something like this could be an optimisation:

```
def test(t, d):
    d = sorted(d)
    total = 0
    size = len(d)
    for x in range(size - 2):
        if d[x] <= t:                      # Check need for two inner loops.
            for i in range(x + 1, size - 1):
                if d[x] + d[i] <= t:       # Check need for inner loop.
                    for j in range(i + 1, size):
                        if d[x] + d[i] + d[j] <= t:
                            total += 1
    return total
```

Although the problem with that is that it still carries on the *current* loop, just ignoring the loops inside that one. It's an even better option to stop the current loop completely since no future iteration of it will deliver useful results:

```
def test(t, d):
    d = sorted(d)
    total = 0
    size = len(d)
    for x in range(size - 2):
        if d[x] > t:                         # Exit loop on impossibility.
            break
        for i in range(x + 1, size - 1):
            if d[x] + d[i] > t:              # Ditto.
                break
            for j in range(i + 1, size):
                if d[x] + d[i] + d[j] > t:   # Ditto.
                    break
                total += 1
    return total
```

Comment: This is good but the second example I posted was more efficient and it became a bit more faster due to your recommendation of breaking early

Answer (score 0):

I can see another optimization to @paxdiablo's answer.  You can stop the loop you're in completely as soon as you go over t, rather than just not doing the body of the remaining iterations of that loop:

```
def test(t, d):
    d = sorted(d)
    total = 0
    size = len(d)
    for x in range(size - 2):
        if d[x] > t:
            break
        for i in range(x+1, size - 1):
            if d[x] + d[i] > t:
                break
            for j in range(i+1, size):
                if (d[x] + d[i] + d[j]) > t:
                    break
                total += 1
    return total
```